# Using glmrob function in R with proportional/percentage dependent variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, percentage

I have performed a `glmrob` to infer whether belonging to one of the treatment groups causes a higher % in success. I have used the following code:

```
rob5 <- glmrob(Num_ofSuccess/Total_No_Reports~RGamDesStrat3, weights = Total_No_Reports, 
               family = binomial, data = MyMasterThesisDataRSTUDIOV3, method = "Mqle", 
               control = glmrobMqle.control(tcc = 3.5))
```

The `num_ofsuccess` represents the total number of reports there were successful, and `total_no` represents the total number reported.

The results that I received are as follows:

```
Coefficients:
                      Estimate      Std. Error  
(Intercept)            0.5108        0.3266       
RGamDesStrat3(0,1]     2.2088        0.4744  
RGamDesStrat3(1,2]     2.1638        0.4346
```

All the estimates are significant. However, the estimates 2.2088 and 2.1638 are impossible to interpret since the DV can only range from 0 to 1. I am unsure what I might have done wrong. Any advice on how to continue?

Comment: I am voting to leave this open as it is really about statistics - the same issue could arise with any software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the *parameter estimates* are above 2 really has little to do with the DV being bounded by 0 and 1. When you put in "family = binomial" then by default you get a logit link, so you are estimating the logit of the proportion of successes. These parameter estimates would then go into a formula for estimating that.

You can get the predicted values for the proportion by using fitted.values.  Those values should be between 0 and 1.